# Execute a selenium script in javascript on button click

Tags: javascript, php, selenium

I am using I wrote a small selenium script in javascript that executes find with node (filename.js) in the terminal but when I try to execute that script with a button click it doesnt work.

I took the guts out and put an alert() and it executed.

Just wondering if anyone can spot what I am doing wrong here?

Here is the script

```
async function example() {

const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("selenium-webdriver");
require("chromedriver");
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();

await driver.get("http://google.com");
await driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Selenium Test", Key.RETURN);
```

}

And here is the php file I want to execute it from

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Sidebar 01</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<center>
    <button onclick="example();">Hello</button>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you find the element and use click(), instead of the Return key?

Comment: I think you are confused, I am not trying to find the the element, I am trying to execute my script by my php file when I manually click on the Hello button but it doesnt execute. Does that make sense ?

Comment: I got it now, can you show me the console logs of chrome when you actually click the Hello button?

Comment: index.js:3 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at example (index.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: You cannot use require!! in this case! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059580/client-on-node-js-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined

Comment: I tried several options including requirejs and browserfly, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you try import and module exports method mentioned in thet answer?

Comment: It now gives me undefined error

Comment: So I figure out how to bypass the require error by using broswerify, my only issue now is being able to call the bundle.js on button click

Comment: Any luck with this approach? Or are you still stuck?

Comment: First I would like to thank you in still showing interest in helping me solve my problem, So my problem is that when I execute the selenium script it is being block from running, strange considering it was running before, could be a security issue ?

Comment: Actually a dumb question and might not be related, is the browser opening up and if yes, what are the permissions coming/showing up for the webpage?

Comment: Not a dumb question at all, The browser doesnt open up anymore and when it did it didnt show permissions

Comment: Cannot find module './atoms/get-attribute.js' is where I am stuck

https://waelyasmina.com/browserify-tutorial-for-total-beginners/

Also, try the -headless option. I think what you are trying to achieve requires some heavy research.

Comment: Update: I am using puppeteer instead of selenium, I have the bundle.js file that properly executes my script, the problem now is like before, I can execute the script on page load but I want it to be triggered at the click of a button.

Comment: Can you update your sample code?